# Creating two inner joins to get wanted result in linq .net, is there a smarter way?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Here are the two joins i currently have made.

```
public ItemDescriptionIdentity GetDescriptionIdentityInfo(int tradeItemId)
{
    var query = (from item in _db.TradeItems
                 join identity in _db.ItemIdentities on item.itemIdentities equals identity.id
                 where item.id == tradeItemId
                 select identity.id).Single();

    var result = (from identitys in _db.ItemDescriptionIdentitiesOnTradeItems
                  join descriptionIdentity in _db.ItemDescriptionIdentities on identitys.itemDescriptionIdentitieId equals descriptionIdentity.id
                  where identitys.itemIdentitiesId == query
                  select descriptionIdentity);

    return result.FirstOrDefault() as ItemDescriptionIdentity;
}
```

In order to get the ItemDescriptionIdentity, i first need to make a join where i find the identity id so i have that for when i make the last join. The two joins works fine. But is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: This is much simpler with navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold what is that? i haven't heard of it before.

Comment: For instance `item.ItemIdentity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ItemDescriptionIdentity GetDescriptionIdentityInfo(int tradeItemId)
{
    var query = (from item in _db.TradeItems
                 join identity in _db.ItemIdentities 
                   on item.itemIdentities equals identity.id
                 join identitys in _db.ItemDescriptionIdentitiesOnTradeItems
                   on identitys.itemIdentitiesId equals identity.id
                 join descriptionIdentity in _db.ItemDescriptionIdentities
                   on identitys.itemDescriptionIdentitieId equals descriptionIdentity.id
                  where item.id == tradeItemId
                  select descriptionIdentity);

    return result.FirstOrDefault() as ItemDescriptionIdentity;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a smart way of doing it. By mergin them togheter as one instead of making two

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I got your model correctly but you could maybe replace the query in your second part with something like

```
(_db.TradeItems.Where(ti => ti.id==tradeItemId).First().itemIdentities.First().id)
```

My assumptions: There is a list of TradeItems, where you can pick one with the passed in `tradeItemId`. Don't know which type is there, but you could look for a method like `FindByKey`. Be sure that you never pass an id without a corresponding TradeItem (otherwise use `FirstOrDefault' and include error handling).

This instance of a tradeItem seems to have a property "itemIdentities" (which seems to be a list... Are there any criteria to find the right identity?). I just pick the first and return its id.